# Upload image to someones Google Drive, Dropbox or Box service

Tags: android, google-drive-api, dropbox-api, box-api, google-drive-android-api

I am looking into my storage options for an app I am making and was wondering if it would be possible to have a user be able to upload images to a users Google Drive, Dropbox or Box with their API's.

the use-case is the user creates a folder on their storage service where other users can upload the images to and then from the other users device/s they select an image to upload to the service owners folder they created without having a drive,drobbox or box account.

Using one or all of these services would allow me to lower the price of it since I would not have to worry about storage costs if I used my own server which obviously would be more attractive to users

I am aware that you can share a public url to the folder but do they have read/write privileges or just read privelages with that url?

Comment: Be clear who's account you will be using. For Google you have a choice of 3: (1) the user's own account, (2) a service account (a pseudo account for your app), (3) a new user account dedicated to the app.

Comment: @pinoyyid how do you specify the drive account in the google play services API, I dont see anywhere where you give an account

Comment: If the upload is being done directly from Android (ie. not using a proxy service), then you are limited to option 1. If you follow the Android Drive Quickstart, you'll see how it uses the AccountManager picker. Obviously I don't know your app specifics, but if it was me, I would probably do all of the drive/box/dropbox stuff using an appengine proxy, so your deployed android app simply needs to communicate with a single service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Is it] possible to have a user be able to upload images to a users Google Drive, Dropbox or Box with their API's

Yes. Your app will need to get an OAuth(2) token for each service, which requires that the user explicitly grant your app access to their files.

> I am aware that you can share a public url to the folder but do they have read/write privileges or just read privelages with that url?

Thar be dragons. Use the APIs; this is what they're for.